# How to solve this Git SourceTree conflict?

Tags: unity, version-control, git

I have recently joined a amateur studio as the single programmer. The previous programmers have left me the project folder. Upon trying to create a repository and a new remote to have version control I encountered a problem. Upon using source tree a lot of previous versions appeared, on a pretty long branch, somehow it knew all the previous versions and who made them.

Now, upon trying to push them to a new remote I created, as I do not have access to the old one, I get a conflict problem and upon pulling I get another.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags --set- 
upstream ********* master:master
Pushing to https://github.com/*******
To https://github.com/******
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com***'


hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.



Completed with errors, see above.
```

f

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks fetch ***

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks pull --no-commit 
****
 master
From https://github.com/********
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
Completed with errors, see above.
```

Comment: Your push is saying that there already exists commits on the remote branch, so Git letting you know that your local commits are different from what's on the remote. If you recently created your repo on Github, you may have checked one of the options that creates a commit for (such as the create README). You can either do a push --force; resolve the conflict yourself; or delete the repo and create an empty one, then try to push.

Comment: @funseiki This looks like it would be worth writing up as an Answer below that users can upvote.